# How to save, delete, edit data to PHP / Mysql with inline edit in CKEditorsaving?

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax, ckeditor

I want to use "inline edit" of the new CKEditor 4 (http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_inline-section-2), but can not find any example of how to save the data with PHP / MySQL. Can you help me?

Comment: use jquery $.ajax http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I think the guide has make it very clear on how to get the data: `CKEDITOR.instances[id].getData();`. Put this data in some hidden field and you can save it like you normally do with traditional form.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a example on how to pass data from the Ckeditor. By pressing the button you can save the content via ajax.

```
<div id="editable" contenteditable="true">
    <h1>Inline Editing in Action!</h1>
    <p>The div element that contains this text is now editable.
</div>
<button type='button' id='save'><span>Save</span></button>

<script>

   $(document).ready(function (e) {

      $("#save").click(function (e) {
          var data = CKEDITOR.instances.editable.getData();
          var options = {  
               url: "/path/to/php",
              type: "post",
              data: { "editor" : encodeUriComponent(data) },
             success: function (e) {
                 //code to do when success
             }

           };
      }
   });
</script>
```